# AngularJS Расчёт пройденного дней/времени от даты

Tags: angularjs

Из БД вывожу время последнего входа пользователя:

```
<tbody ng-app="testApp" ng-controller='TestCntr'>
          <tr ng-repeat='user in login'>
               <td>
              {{ user.updated_at|date:("d.m.Y G:i") }}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Формат исходной даты: `2017-10-02 23:50`

Скажите, реально ли вывести количество дней или, если время не превышает 24 часа, время пройденное с последнего входа пользователя?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В пакете [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) есть директива `am-time-ago` она показывает сколько время прошло с указанной даты. Если не то, тогда нужно свою директиву написать.